# How to set up APC on Drupal 7 with httpd + fastcgi?

Tags: 7, caching, performance

Can you recommend how to set up APC for a site running Drupal 7 on apache2 with fastcgi ?

I got to the point where apc.php shows only one file cached that is apc.php itself.
I cannot see if APC cache is used at all when accessing Drupal nodes.

PHPinfo shows:

```
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
```

**apc**

```
APC Support enabled
Version 3.1.9
APC Debugging   Disabled
MMAP Support    Enabled
MMAP File Mask  /dev/zero
Locking type    pthread mutex Locks
Serialization Support   php

Directive   Local Value Master Value
apc.cache_by_default    On  On
apc.canonicalize    On  On
apc.coredump_unmap  Off Off
apc.enable_cli  On  On
apc.enabled On  On
apc.file_md5    Off Off
apc.file_update_protection  2   2
apc.filters no value    no value
apc.gc_ttl  3600    3600
apc.include_once_override   On  On
apc.lazy_classes    Off Off
apc.lazy_functions  Off Off
apc.max_file_size   1M  1M
apc.mmap_file_mask  /dev/zero   /dev/zero
apc.num_files_hint  1024    1024
apc.preload_path    no value    no value
apc.report_autofilter   Off Off
apc.rfc1867 On  On
apc.rfc1867_freq    0   0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_ upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600    3600
apc.serializer  default default
apc.shm_segments    1   1
apc.shm_size    30M 30M
apc.slam_defense    On  On
apc.stat    On  On
apc.stat_ctime  Off Off
apc.ttl 7200    7200
apc.use_request_time    On  On
apc.user_entries_hint   4096    4096
apc.user_ttl    7200    7200
apc.write_lock  On  On
```

**cgi-fcgi**

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
cgi.check_shebang_line  1   1
cgi.fix_pathinfo    1   1
cgi.force_redirect  1   1
cgi.nph 0   0
cgi.redirect_status_env  no value   no value
cgi.rfc2616_headers 0   0
fastcgi.logging 1   1
```

I would like to use boost + memcache + apc eventually but currently I have a problem enabling apc on httpd with fastcgi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We finally managed to set this up properly.

Apc works fine for multiple processes with apache/2 + php 5.3.x + php-fpm + fcgi in FPM/FastCGI mode.

PHP 5.3.x is configured with following options
--enable-force-cgi-redirect 
--enable-fastcgi 
--enable-fpm

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post about this a a few weeks ago, might be useful to some as it goes into a bit more detail. It uses shared memory for APC rather than anonymous mmapped memory (When apc.mmap_file_mask = /dev/zero). This *may* be better for performance but I was unable to find a conclusive answer.

Also I think that anonymously mmapped memory ***might*** not be shared amongst the FPM children, but it may have just been something else I did wrong / came across when doing this setup. Before I used shared memory, I would usually be served by the same PHP process when accessing the APC status page, but if I left it a while and tried again, the APC status page would show a different value for apc.mmap_file_mask, which would mean there was more than one APC cache being used overall since I had not restarted PHP-FPM in this time. Though again, I'm not certain about this.

Anyway, how I setup [Apache MPM Worker, PHP-FPM, FastCGI and APC](http://failover.co.za/2012/01/29/setup-apache-mpm-worker-fastcgi-php-fpm-apc/).